# Bootstrap 3 theme effects

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This isn't really me asking how to do this but a pointer really in regards to producing the effect an example Bootstrap theme I have seen and for other websites too not just bootstrap.

[Bootstrap 3 Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/nonus-one-page-parallax-html-portfolio/full_screen_preview/5242349)

The introduction of the site fills the browser window every which way on all screen sizes and I have always had trouble achieving this. What are the best ways to approach this and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough; you need to set the height of the `div` (or other element you use to hold the full screen content) to '100%', but this needs to be *relative* to '*something*' which is why you also set height:100% for the `html` (viewport) and `body` (content) elements. As long as the div with the image appears first in your HTML, it will work as anticipated.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/z4zhk/)

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}
#imgDiv{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(myImage.png);
}
```

Comment: So this imgDiv will fill the entire screen no matter how you manipulate the browser window? And if another div was added below it will still hold its own as a 100% high div?

Comment: Absolutely, feel free to give it a go :)

Comment: Think you have answered my question :) I am troubled as to enable another div below to slide over that top div so is it possible to make the top div fixed (including text on top of it) and the second div to scroll over it?

Comment: @user3520443 - you may want to open a new question for that so as to get maximum coverage by the community

Comment: Thank you - I shall do - May I use you example Fiddle?

Comment: @user3520443 - sure, its all public property :)